# CreateFile() Failed With GetLastError() = 5

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have written a sample application to read the file from the other file. When I run this application form virtual machine I am getting Access denied.  Below is the code.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WCHAR *wcsPath = L"\\\\150.160.130.22\\share\\123.XML";

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(wcsPath,
                               GENERIC_READ,
                               FILE_SHARE_READ,
                               NULL,
                               OPEN_EXISTING,
                               0,
                               0);

    if (NULL == hFile)
    {
        printf("failed - %d", GetLastError());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Please let me know any changes.

Comment: See if you can open the said file with Notepad. The rights are per-user, not per-program - if you cannot read it from Notepad, your program won't either.

Comment: i can open it in notepad

Comment: You have to check if the user running the program has the right to open the file, the right to open the share and that the file is not opened in another program.

Comment: From the virtual machine, open Explorer, locate the file. Then goto a `Security` tab. Click `Advanced`. Click `Effective Permissions`, and check if you do have all required permissions.

Answer (score 10):

Error code 5 stands for "Access is Denied". You should check your user's access rights.

Comment: Who? What account do you use to run your program?

Comment: Well, I believe you are. WHAT IS THE ACCOUNT YOU USE TO RUN YOUR PROGRAM?

Comment: @loki2302: He's on Windows so it would be the account he logged in with (unless it's a service or impersonation involved, and he said nothing about such things).

Comment: Depending on the VM settings and the environment, the account might or might not have network share access.

Comment: Solved it for me, thanks! Where can one find the list of codes and their meaning?

Answer (score 2):

I believe [the documentation for CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) holds the answer.

It *may be* that your *dwShareMode*  is causing the problem.  Using `FILE_SHARE_READ` there says, "allow other openers to open the file for READ access".  If you do not specify FILE_SHARE_WRITE` , then other openers will not be able to open the file for writing - your call would prevent that.

But, CreateFile, I believe, also fails when the sharemode would be violated by prior openers.  If this is true, then if another application already has the file open for write access, then your call to CreateFile will fail, if you specify dwShareMode = `FILE_SHARE_READ`.  Do you see?  You may need to specify `FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ`  for that dwShareMode parameter.

Try it.

Comment: This is probably not the case - the error message for an incompatible share mode should be `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`.

Answer (score 1):

The error output of CreateFileW() is INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, not NULL. Now, NULL definitely sounds like a wrong value for a file handle too, but still.

Is the pasted code snippet exactly the content of your program, or a retelling?

EDIT: I see there's a VM involved. Can you open the file in Notepad *from the virtual machine where the program is running and erroring out*?

Comment: i have changed only ip address

Comment: yes you are right if this fails it gives INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.

Comment: What is the IP address? Is this the host computer? Or a server somewhere on the network?

Comment: So how exactly are you opening the file in Notepad? Not by drag-drop from the host machine's Explorer, by any chance? What I want you to try is to open the file *exactly* by the same UNC path as your program. File/Open, paste the path string (mind the double-backslashes), click Open. See if that works.

Comment: @Seva: I predict you're right.  It's probably permission settings on the share.

Comment: Notepad may use a different `FILE_SHARE_*` setting.  It may use FILE_SHARE_WRITE or FILE_SHARE_DELETE.